# bootstrap 4.x list-group spinning icon in button while active

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make an icon spin inside the button of the bootstrap list group item while active. my problem is, I'm not as well versed in Js as i am in CSS and HTML. I can add the "fa-spin" to the class to make it spin but then it spins all the time. I want the icons to spin only while the list-group-item is active.

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active center" id="list-Dec-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-Dec" role=tab aria-controls="Dec">
    <i class="fas fa-info fa-spin"></i>
</a>
```

here is the code i'm working with for one of my list-group-items, the others are exactly the same except that the icons are different and the id's are different (obviously). Thank you for your responses and I hope y'all have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without javascript by having two icons, one spinning, one not spinning, and just toggling the display based on the `active` class.

HTML:

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active center" id="list-Dec-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-Dec" role=tab aria-controls="Dec">
    <i class="fas fa-info nospin"></i><i class="fas fa-info fa-spin"></i>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.list-group-item > .fa-spin { display: none; }
a.list-group-item.active > .fa-spin { display: block; }
a.list-group-item.active > .nospin { display: none; }
```